# SwiftUI Realm: cannot modify List outside of a write transaction

Tags: swiftui, realm

I'm learning SwiftUI and Realm by making a Todo app, there are two objects: `Todo` and `Task`, a `Todo` must have a task, so if creating a `Todo` for the first time, a `Task` must be created:

[image: New Todo]

After adding a task, it will appear in the "Task" picker. The code is like this:

```swift
struct CreateTodoView: View {

  @State private var task: TaskObject?

  @ObservedResults(TaskObject.self) var tasks
  @ObservedResults(Todo.self) var todos

  var body: some View {
    // …
    Picker("Task", selection: $task) {
      Text("- Select Task -").tag(nil as TaskObject?)
      ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
        Text(task.name).tag(task as TaskObject?)
      }
    }
    Button {
      guard let task else { return }
      let todo = Todo()
      todo.date = //…
      $todos.append(todo) // 1. this works
      try! realm.write { task.todos.append(todo) } // 2. this doesn't work
    } label: {
      Text("Save")
    }
    // …
  }
}
```

When I followed Realm's doc using `@ObservedResults` (1) and add the newly created `Todo` to `todos`, it works without problem, the thing is I also want to add the todo to the selected task, but doing so (2) leads to:

> cannot modify List outside of a write transaction.

I know it might be using a different Realm instance, but just wondering if is there an easy way to achieve this while still using the convenient `@ObservedResults`?

There's also an `@ObservedObject` but it cannot be optional, so I can't assign the selected task to it when a task is selected.

Thanks!

Update:

I've updated the code as per comment suggested, so now I've only have the list of tasks as `@ObservedResults`, new Todo object is created and added to selected task, but I'm still getting the same error:

```swift
struct TodoView: View {

    //@ObservedResults(Todo.self) var todos
    @ObservedResults(TaskObject.self) var tasks

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State private var todoName: String = ""
    @State private var selectedTask: TaskObject?

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField(text: $todoName) {
                Text("Name")
            }
            Picker("Task", selection: $selectedTask) {
                Text("No Task").tag(Optional<TaskObject>(nil))
                ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
                    Text(task.name).tag(Optional<TaskObject>(task))
                }
            }
            if let task = selectedTask {
                Text("Selected task: \(task.name)")
            }
            Button {
                let todo = Todo(name: todoName)
                if let task = selectedTask {
                    task.todos.append(todo)
                }
                //$todos.append(todo)
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
            .disabled(selectedTask == nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:
I finally figured out a solution that seems to work, here's the Button action part:

```swift
Button {
    let todo = Todo(name: todoName)
    if let task = selectedTask, let thawed = task.thaw(), let realm = thawed.realm {
        try! realm.write {
            thawed.todos.append(todo)
        }
    }
    //$todos.append(todo)
    dismiss()
}
```

Need to read more about Realm :-)

Comment: have you tried removing `guard let task else { return }`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine No I haven't, I don't think it's related.

Comment: maybe not be related, but you have a `let task`, try `guard var task else { return }`

Comment: Your models were not included but it appears a TaskObject has a child property of a List of ToDo's. If that's the case you don't need this `@ObservedResults(Todo.self) var todos` as all of the Tasks ToDos can be accessed through the parent Task property. Also, take note that *When you use the @ObservedRealmObject or @ObservedResults property wrappers, you can implicitly open a write transaction* which is called a quick write, meaning `try! realm.write` is not needed. It may help to go through [SwiftUI Write](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#write-data---swiftui)

Comment: Thanks @Jay I've updated the code to have only tasks but still getting the same error.

Comment: I think the initial issue is here `task.todos.append(todo)` as that attempting to modify the `task` object outside of a write transaction. Not sure what this - *so I can't assign the selected task to it when a task is selected* references as if you have a list of tasks, not the existing tasks would ever be optional as if it were, it would not exist. You fix 'works' but you shouldn't need to do that.